# Create an input field with auto-complete in a PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, autocomplete

How would I go about creating an auto-complete field in a PHP form? I have a list of manufacturers (which can be either in a CSV or listed into a database table) which I would like the auto-complete to refer to.

I figure I'd have to use jquery or similar.

Comment: checkout jQuery-UI autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery plugins (using AJAX), Here are few links.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete), which does exactly your needs and uses AJAX.